# PHP replacing the correct tags

Tags: php, str-replace

I have quite an odd question I think.

Lets say I have a piece of code loaded into a string variable in PHP :

```
$my_variable = array('mykey' => 'myvalue', 'children' => array('some value', 'oh and sure another value', 'childvalues' => get_child_values()));
```

Now what I want is a piece of code that replaces the array() elements by [].
I can of course do

```
str_replace(['array(', ')'], ['[', ']'], $str);
```

But that ain't gonna work.

Because it would replace the last element of each and every value. Incorrectly. So I want the code to wrap the corresponding tags.

So the code in the variable will look like :

```
$my_variable = ['mykey' => 'myvalue', 'children' => ['some value', 'oh and sure another value', 'childvalues' => get_child_values()]];
```

But I have given it a go but I got bogged down because I cannot think of a correct logic to achieve this.

I hope someone has an idea how to do this in a 'simple' manner.

Comment: Why are you bothering? Also genuine

Comment: Genuine question - Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Because actually replacing array( with [ speeds up massively. I never thought this would be such a performance increase. But it actually increases performance. And I have written several large applications that still use array() and I would like to convert all of that within a short amount of time to []

Comment: Benchmark: looping 5000 times Result: `Using array() Execution Time: 0.0036 seconds
Using [] Execution Time: 0.0015 seconds` but results are often inconsistant `Using array() Execution Time: 0.0037 seconds Using [] Execution Time: 0.0038 seconds` Is it really worth your bother, do you often create an array 5000 times in one script

Comment: I mean parsing string for properly find and replace all arrays will more expensive when native code interpretation